# Grid search vs Best subset selection

Tags: machine-learning

I didn't understand what is the difference between this two model selection procedures: Grid search, Best subset selection .
Both of them pick up a subset of parameters and try all possible combinations of them, so I don't understand where is the difference.

Answer (score 0):

**Subset Selection** in machine learning is used for features selection and it means evaluating a subset of features (out of all potential features) as a group and then selecting the best subset by some criteria.

There are many different algorithms for doing so, one of them is a grid search of all possible subsets.

**Grid search** is just the most simple way to search thru hyperparameters, it is an exhaustive search through a manually specified subset of the hyperparameters.

So, Best subset selection can be done by grid search, but there are also other approaches.